# Code runs without pointer being initialized

Tags: c++

The below code runs perfectly fine and prints "Executed".

I don't understand how this can be possible if pointer "p" is NULL ??

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Foo
{
    public:
    Foo(int i = 0){ _i = i;}
    void f()
    {
        cout << "Executed"<<endl;
    }
    private:
    int _i;
};
int main()
{
    Foo *p = NULL;
    p -> f();
}
```

Comment: As the old saying goes, undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: A lot of the times in C++, failing to follow the rules is not required to explicitly crash or fail. Anything can happen, including exactly what you expected. It is still an error.

Comment: Why would you say that it "runs fine" when it didn't do what you expected? Generally, we only describe code as "running fine" if it does what we expected.

Comment: Note that once you go UB, there's no going back. You cannot really check for `this == nullptr` inside the member function, compilers will happily remove the if.

Comment: thanks for the comments. But if the pointer is literally is NULL, how it makes the call?? I guess its just unexpected behaviour

Comment: @ali In a typical implementation the pointer is effectively passed as a hidden parameter to a method. Obviously NULL can be passed as a parameter without any problem. If you examined `this` inside the `f` method you might find that it is also NULL.

Comment: So shall I delete the question?

Comment: @ali no. keep it there. Your question will likely be found through searches and newcomers will be rerouted to the other already answered question.

Comment: @ali Your code is a bit equivalent to `f(nullptr)` as if `f` was `f(Foo*)`. You can still call `f`, it's just that the hidden `this` parameter is null.

However, be aware to not rely on this as it is undefined behavior to call a member function on a null object. It could crash if for example you try to access a data member. For a non member function, the behavior is defined even if some parameter are null.

Comment: @ali If you're curious, I suggest you to try [reading the assembly here](https://godbolt.org/z/xoYXq2), and try it with virtual functions.

Comment: Thanks for the link